# Dynamic template controls in knockout.js with add/remove functionality

Tags: templates, dynamic, knockout.js

Better if I explain this splitting. 
The first one: I have to add and remove a line of controls (it's working)
The second one: Depending on a selected option in a control, I have to show different options or controls. (it's working also with templates).

The problem is to make both of them work together. Each time I add a line, then select an option, then show the option/control/text, and then be able to remove also that line.

Thanks in advance.

```
HTML:

<table data-bind="foreach: fLines">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: formatValues, value: type"></select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="template: type"></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" data-bind='click: $parent.removefLine'>Remove</a>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<button style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" data-bind="click: addfLine()">Add Format</button>

<script id="A" type="text/html">
    <input data-bind="value: value1" /> 
</script>

<script id="B" type="text/html">
    <span>removes leading and trailing spaces</span>
</script>

<script id="C" type="text/html">
</script>

KO:

var formatValues = ["A", "B", "C"];

var Item = function(format) {
    var self = this;
    self.type = ko.observable(format);
    self.value1 = ko.observable();
};

var Formatters = {
    fLines: [ new Item("C") ],
    addfLine: function(){fLines.push(new Item("C"))}
};


ko.applyBindings(Formatters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.  'formatValues' needed to be part of the viewmodel to participate in databinding.

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.formatValues, value: type"></select>
```

[JSFiddle with add/remove](http://jsfiddle.net/LeCodeNinja/SJFhM/)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Corey, the fiddle you added worked perfectly